# Book where wolf like aliens attack a human spaceship and leave them stranded on their home world where gravity is twice as strong as Earth's

Tags: story-identification, books

There was a book that I read 2 years ago but I can’t remember what it was called!

It starts with a space vessel leaving a sector of space, I think it was a carrier full of scientists? But while they are out the captain knows of a ship that was lost in the sector they are jumping to. As they reach the sector some aliens board the ship, kinda wolf like and they rush around really fast and are twice as strong. As if they were used to a stronger gravity. As they start to take over the ship, making their way to the bridge, the captain quickly orders a ship wide panic, having everyone hide. The unknown creatures take over the ship and order their captain to take them back to the creatures homeland.

They arrive at the homeland and gravity is 2 times as harsher compared to what humans were used to, and they have to fight a lot of the the creatures they don’t even know about as the Wolf like creatures leave them on their planet so they can duel them when they return. I don’t remember anything to much past that in the rest of the series, other than they meet and make peace with a sabertooth like cat on the world, and they start to genetically modify themselves so they can work better on the world, and having children who are used to everything and are twice as fast. The kids learn how to work the alien space ship that was left behind and they all start to rush back to Earth with their new abilities to stop them from attacking the sector before they reach Earth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds remarkably like the *Koban* series by [**Stephen W Bennett**](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/b/stephen-w-bennett/)

> We colonized seven hundred planets. Humankind enjoyed the benefits of expansion room and the end of wars. We even disbanded our military.
>
> Then the Krall found us.
>
> The Krall have used thousands of years of combat to select the genes of the strongest and fastest warriors. They are a species determined to dominate the entire galaxy, through destruction and annihilation of every opponent.
>
> Koban is an uninhabited high gravity planet with impossibly fast savage animals, which employ organic superconducting nerves. This deadly world is where the Krall tested humans for war capability. We are useful only if we can fight well. If not, they will destroy us swiftly, as they have others. They already have slave races, and we are poor tasting meat animals. The Krall will use us, if worthy, to seek physical perfection using the attrition of war, one planet at a time.
>
> Growing weary of human physical weakness, the ruthless Krall are on the verge of a decision to eliminate our race quickly. A ship containing bio-scientists is captured for combat testing on Koban. The urgent choice for Captain Mirikami and the scientists is simple: Prove we can produce better, smarter fighters, or humanity is doomed to rapid extermination, rather than the slow eradication the Krall prefer.

There are 7 books in the primary series as it happens

1. Koban (2012)
2. The Mark of Koban (2013)
3. Rise of the Kobani (2013)
4. Shattered Worlds (2014)
5. A Federation Forged in Fire (2015)
6. Conflict and Empire (2016)
7. When Empires Collide (2017)

Comment: Yes!! That’s it! Koban! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like it might be *The Survivors* by Tom Godwin. See [Humans escape earth destruction and go to alien planet generations later for revenge](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/182698/).  Certainly the story is the same in many important respects.

Comment: Could you edit the to explain how it matches the OP's description?

Comment: No that is not it but it does sound interesting.